# How to correctly match constructors with typescript

Tags: typescript

I have implemented a function `JavaAdapter` to inherit classes and return instantiated objects. Now I'm creating a declaration for it.

```js
type ProxyMethods<T extends object> = { [K in keyof T]?: T[K] } | {};

declare function JavaAdapter<T, K extends ProxyMethods<T>, Args>(
  className: new (...args: Args) => T,
  override: K,
  ...args: Args
): K & T;
```

In most cases, it works fine. However, when the inherited object has multiple constructor functions with different parameter counts, it cannot accurately match, for example:

```js
JavaAdapter(
  android.widget.Button,
  {
    setOnClickListener(view) {
      console.log(view);
    },
  },
  activity,
  // new android.util.AttributeSet()
);
```

This usage is correct and matches one of the constructor functions, but TypeScript prompts "Expected 4 arguments, but got 3." It works only when I add new android.util.AttributeSet(). The partial declaration of `android.widget.Button` is as follows:

```js
declare module android {
  export module widget {
    class Button {
      public setOnClickListener(view: this): void;
      public constructor(context: android.content.Context);
      public constructor(context: android.content.Context, attribute: android.util.AttributeSet);
    }
  }
}
```

Besides changing to `constructor(context: android.content.Context, attribute?: android.util.AttributeSet);`, can TypeScript better adapt?

constructor(context: android.content.Context, attribute?: android.util.AttributeSet);

Comment: TypeScript can't currently resolve overloads in the abstract, only when you actually call an overload directly. When you infer from overloaded types, TS tends to pick just the last overload.  This is essentially [ms/TS#35501](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/35501) (and related issues). It's currently a design limitation although there has been some work which might address it in a future TS version. Does that fully address the question? If so I'll write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?